# How to Install git in google compute engine?

Tags: git, github, prestashop, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I used bitnami stack to setup a new vm instance on Google compute engine. 
The stack had prestashop preinstalled with it. I would like to pull prestahop code localy, make changes and push live.
Should i install git on the instance manually?
In google console there is an option to connect a repository with github repository, this only works for google engine, not for compute? 
How can i install git or use any other service google provides for this instance and edit existing code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I actually have a similar setup.  I installed Bitnami's Redmine VM on google cloud compute.

Most Bitnami VMs come with git installed, but not all. So try this:

Login to your Google Cloud Instance.

then run (omitting the `$`, of course):

```
$ which git
```

should display something like

```
/usr/bin/git
```

if not, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Allow the update to run. Then run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Allow the install to run.  Now running:

```
$ which git
```

should return something like:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

Now, if you don't yet have a repository setup remotely go do that at [www.github.com](http://www.github.com), [www.bitbucket.com](http://www.bitbucket.com), or whatever service you use.

Now, go to `/opt/bitnami/apps/[app-name]/htdocs` on your VM:

```
$ cd /opt/bitnami/apps/[app-name]/htdocs
```

Then:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git remote add origin <URL_TO_YOUR_REPO>
$ git push -u origin master
```

Now your instance files should be in your repo.  You should now be able to clone and change locally, and pull changes on your Google Cloud VM.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: You may need to do some git configuration. See [Git Configuration](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: Bitnami Prestashop stack didnt had git installed. I installed in manullay but the rest worked like charm!

Comment: You are right. Not all Bitnami VMs come with git installed, I noticed this in an OSQA VM I was testing out the other day.  I have edited my answer to remove that remark.